# java integer handling

Tags: java

When I run this program, it outputs -43.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=053;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Why is this? How did 053 turn into -43?

Answer (score 10):

I've no idea how it's becoming negative, but starting an integer with `0` specifies it's octal (base eight). `53` in base eight is `43` in base ten.

Comment: BTW, in my machine it returns 43, not -43

Answer (score 3):

The java tutorials http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

```
 int decVal = 26;      // The number 26, in decimal
 int octVal = 032;     // The number 26, in octal <<== LOOK FAMILIAR?
 int hexVal = 0x1a;    // The number 26, in hexadecimal
 int binVal = 0b11010; // The number 26, in binary
```

Yup... it's a gotcha!

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 1):

It prints out 43, not -43.  That is because if you write a number with a leading 0, it is an octal constant.

From here, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

> int octVal = 032;        // The number 26, in octal

Comment: Nahhh... I'm just on the other side of the planet from the nearest SOF server... I have never supplied the first answer to any question, and I don't expect to... the question is (I suspect) a few minutes old before I even see it.

Answer (score 0):

This from googling 'how to convert octal to decimal'

**Octal to Decimal**

1. Start the decimal result at 0.
2. Remove the most significant octal digit (leftmost) and add it to the result.
3. If all octal digits have been removed, you're done. Stop.
4. Otherwise, multiply the result by 8.
5. Go to step 2.

So 0 + 5 = 5, 5 * 8 = 40, 40 + 3 = 43

Answer (score 0):

As http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1 says:

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

And its format is:

```
OctalNumeral:
    0 OctalDigits
    0 Underscores OctalDigits
```

So, if you use

```
int octVal = 053;
```

or,

```
int octVal = 0_53;
```

both of them, you will get 43.